# Passing an array to a Class not just a Method

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I have made this sample code to pass an array to and from a method, changing the original array in the process.

```
public class ArrayPasserMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] lifegrid = {0,1,2};
        ArrayPass(lifegrid);
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            System.out.println(lifegrid[i]);
        }
    }

    static void ArrayPass(int grid[]) {
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            System.out.println(grid[i]); 
            grid[i] = grid[i] + 3;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I write the method ArrayPass in another class with the same results, passing the array over, changing the values and passing it back?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and do us a favor by formatting your post to get one code block. As for your question: you could work with static fields and use methods to access them or make them public but that's not recommended. Instead have a look at how instances work - and how to use getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public class ArrayPasserMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] lifegrid = {0,1,2};
        lifegrid = AnotherClass.changeValues(lifegrid);
    }
}

class AnotherClass {
    static int[] changeValues(int[] grid) {
        for (int i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(grid[i]); 
            grid[i] = grid[i] + 3;
        }
        return grid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try it why? What problem in the OP's code does it fix, and how does it fix it?

Comment: Have you read the question? OP wants to extract the code outside in another class's method.

Comment: @ChrisT you can accept it, in that case.

Comment: @ChrisT - I recommend you to read [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).